# Taking fixnum as user input

Tags: ruby, input

I was wondering if there is a way to take user input as a fixnum. I can do something like `a = gets.chomp.to_i`, but is there anything similar in ruby to `nextInt()` in java, or do I need to do these conversions each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working with input streams, like a file or the terminal, you're working with raw bytes. You never work directly with primitive types. If you want primitive types, you have to use methods to make sense of the bytes. In many cases, "working with raw bytes" is synonymous with working with strings, so strings types often have conversion methods to extract typed data out of them.

Java has the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class, which does have a [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) method. It is used to extract a Java integer out of text. It does so by parsing the text and converting it to the requested primitive data type, in this case `int`. In order for it to work, you must give it an input source. When you wrap it around [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), you get a `Scanner` that extracts data from standard input, which is usually connected to the terminal.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scanner.nextInt();
```

In Ruby, we can simply ask the string to try and convert itself to another type. If you want an integer:

```
line = gets    # reads from standard input
i = line.to_i  # converts the string to an integer
```

String's [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) method performs a very loose conversion, and returns zero if it couldn't figure out the number or if there was no number to begin with. It will never raise an exception and will always return a number, even if there was no number to parse.

The [`Integer()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method performs a more strict conversion.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `gets.chomp.to_i` works, but is not the right way. I don't know how you got that idea to attach `chomp`, but that has no meaning here. You should do `gets.to_i`. So, no, you don't need to do the conversion `gets.chomp.to_i` each time.

And the only thing Ruby can receive from a terminal input is a string. There is no way to receive anything other than a string from the terminal.